# Time lapse not showing features ArcMap 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, time

I am trying to use ArcMap 10 to visualize air quality data. I have created a shapefile with values of measurements of PM2.5 on an interval of 15 minutes each. The total data accounts for circa 3000 measurements and so I am working with this as an example.Now, equal coordinates to each sensor were given since the sensors are static.
The time format I need to show is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss as seen in the TIME field. I have tried to change the field type to date and also to text, text works when defining the time laps parameters on the layer configuration.
I have also selected a category symbology for the values I need to visualize.
When the time series starts, nothing shows. Any idea why is this happening?

Here the [attribute table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh2C6.jpg)! 
Here the [image: categorization]
Here the time lapse with no features shown [image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format

Comment: Have you turned off the "scale symbols" option in layer properties so that your points are visible at the current scale?

Comment: Do they show up when you're not doing a time-lapse? AKA is the coordinate system defined correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have made sure the coordinate system and the "scale symbols" are selected correctly. And, the points are shown when the time is not enabled. When I play the time lapse, however, they disappear.